# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in Python in mathematical programming

Tags: python, oop, mathematical-optimization

I have a funtion defined in a class

```
class someClass:
    def objFunction(self, weights):
        return [self.obj1(weights), self.obj2(weights), self.obj3(weights)]

    def asf(self, f):

        def obj(x):
            return np.max(np.array(f(x[0],x[1],x[2])))+0.00001*np.sum(f(x[0],x[1],x[2]))

        res=minimize(obj, 
        [0.3,0.3,0.4], method='SLSQP'
        ,jac=ad.gh(obj)[0],options = {'disp':True, 'ftol': 1e-20,
                                    'maxiter': 1000})
        return res
```

where obj1, obj2 and obj3 are some objective functions to optimized. I am running this method making an object separately:

```
newObj = SomeClass()
newObj.objFunction(weights)
```

This works fine and give expected results. But when I used the same method inside another method in the class it returns the above mentioned error. This is how I am doing:

```
a = someClass()
a.asf(a.objFunction(weights)
```

It throws this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/*******.py", line 332, in <module>
    print(investment.asf(obj1(w),ref,ideal,nadir, rho))
  File "*******.py", line 313, in asf
   ,options = {'disp':True, 'ftol': 1e-20, 'maxiter': 1000})
  File "C:\Users\*****\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 455, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\*****\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 363, in _minimize_slsqp
    fx = func(x)
  File "C:\Users\*******\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 289, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "D:********.py", line 305, in obj
    return np.max(np.array(f(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])))+rho*np.sum(f(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I think I am doing some OOP (object oriented programming) error in coding because I am not good at it. Any suggestions for this ? Thanks

Comment: Please mention the entire stack-trace. With this error, I could only tell that you are calling list like `list(n)` instead of `list[n]` somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

`a.objFunction(weights)` returns a `list`, that's clear from the definition.

`a.asf` expects one argument called `f`, which in the definition gets used like:

```
f(x[0],x[1],x[2])
```

So you are giving `a.asf` a list and trying to call it like a function.